# mysql table specification for numerous varchar fields

Tags: mysql

I have a table with over 100 columns imported from Access into mysql. the table will be displayed in the typical shared hosting apache environment using PHP and HTML.  Almost all fields were coming in as varchar(255). This caused errors of oversize row length on import so i switched many of them to text(0) for import. I would like to make these fields have a size and varchar type so I can index them for search speed. Each of the fields will only contain maybe at most 10 words. 
I need to the fields to be set to as small as they can be so I don't push past mysql row maximum.

How do I calculate the size I need for the varchar?

I am a noob at mysql so if I am asking something wrong or lack understanding please explain.

Comment: try the import with mysql workbench https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-migration-database-access.html

Comment: thanks will try and see if it the import works better

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(LENGTH(field1)) length_field1,
       MAX(LENGTH(field2)) length_field2,
  --   ..........
       MAX(LENGTH(fieldN)) length_fieldN
FROM source_table;
```

Comment: I think you didnt understand the question. I am not running a query.

Comment: @liz There is only one question in your text. You have asked: "How do I calculate the size I need for the varchar?" I give you a query which will calculate the data which you need in, and allows to create a receiving table structure which will accept the data using minimal row size. What is unclear? PS. As an additional tip, I can offer vertical sharding of the table. This can also solve the described problem.